# LOGIC to retrieve the folder name from the file path in ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I've run into an issue while developing a new package for automating the loading of data from Excel files into a database table. While loading I need to extract the FOLDER NAME in which the Excel file is located, basing on the name of the folder I have to retrieve some other information to be loaded  in database. I need help with the LOGIC to retrieve the folder name from the file path.

Comment: Have you searched `ssis get folder name`?

Comment: Use expression, you can find system function for your expression like findstring, substring, len... use those for your calculation to find the data between 1 before last '\' and the last '\' . thats it, you got your folder name

Answer (score 1):

You can use a script task which will allow you to use the System.IO namespace to get the file information and directory information from your file. You can then assign the values you are trying to extract from the folder info to variables for use in a later step.

Comment: I have done that in script task, but each time the loop runs through it returns only the path for first file and then it exits the loop,i need the loop to run again inorder to return the filepath for other files in folder aswell.

Comment: If all the files are in the same folder, I don't understand the problem. Could you be more specific? Are there multiple folders or subfolders? Are you trying to get the file name along with the folder name?

Comment: there are multiple folders and I need to extract the folder name dynamically

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is with an Expression Task.

To use this approach, you'll need to put the Excel file's full path/name string into a variable ("FullPath" in the below example).

```
@[User::Folder] = SUBSTRING(@[User::Path], 1, 
  LEN(@[User::Path]) - FINDSTRING(REVERSE(@[User::Path]), "\\", 1)
)
```

This expression sets variable "Folder" to the value of "FullPath" minus the last "\" and anything following it. If you feed it `C:\Somewhere\Somewhere Else\More Path\File Name.xlsx`, the expression will set "Folder" to `C:\Somewhere\Somewhere Else\More Path`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following expression:

```
SUBSTRING(@[User::FilePath], 1, 
LEN(@[User::FilePath]) - FINDSTRING(REVERSE(@[User::FilePath] ), "\\" ,1 ) + 1
)
```

More examples [here](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/06/often-used-ssis-expressions.html)